# Installing Apps on External Drives for Use on Multiple Systems

Tags: macos, configuration

With super-fast, high capacity mirrored HDD drives becoming available on the market, I'm considering setting up my workstations in a way that all of my Apps and Data are installed on external drives.

I'm new to this (setting up systems to operate of external drives), and I'm PC based, although agnostic as to whether to continue using PC's or switch to Apple (love Apple but they are pricey!)

My end goal is that the actual workstation (be it a laptop or desktop) has nothing, or as little as possible, installed on it.

I'd like to grab my external hard-drive, plug it into a system, and be up and running.

So for example, if I had two Mac Books (i.e. a MacBook Air and MacBook Pro), and Mac Pro desktop, then all I would need to do is operate of my portable external drive - with all my apps and data available.

Same would go for PC, if possible (i.e. a PC Ultrabook, PC Laptop and PC Desktop).

I'm not looking to do this off a cloud, for the reason that I'm not always guaranteed a fast Internet connection (and at times none at all).  I also like the idea of being able to just give my drive over to collaborators to use on their systems.

1. Is this possible?
2. What software and how would you do it? (Step-by-step would be greatly appreciated!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this to some extend, given the app doesnt need any configuration change in your operating system (eg: registry entry). Make sure to keep any app configuration contained within the app directory itself.

This website has the portable version for most of the apps we use:
http://portableapps.com/

Also make sure you backup your external drive often as they tend to fail faster than internal ones, due to constant handling/movement etc. SSD would be a good option for better performance and reliability, but much costlier. And USB3 would be much faster than USB2 too, since you would be accessing the external disk extensively!

Another option you can consider is to create a VM in the disc, install everything there and then just run this VM from your different machines. It helps to make non-portable apps also portable. This could technically work across multiple OS too. For eg: if you create a Windows VM using Virtual Box, you can host it on different platforms like OSX, Windows, Linux etc:
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads